# JMeter: How to run two thread parallel after completion of first thread

Tags: jmeter

My application is live application & three is a heavy use of AAJX call and Java scripts.

Successful login required three steps

1. Login validation
   On login page browser post user login information and backed first validate it and set cookies & session id for further use. 
   After successfully validation of user information browser initiate two request parallel towards back-end.
2. Browser post a request to server & server send some XML data in every 10 seconds towards browser. Back-end push information in every 10 seconds up to user logged in.
3. Also browser post a ping request to server to make sure user is available and active.

To test the performance of UI by JMeter I am planning to create following test plan.

Test Plan

1. Main Login Thread
2. Ping Thread
3. Application Thread

Now I want to run thread 2 & 3 parallel after completion of first thread.

Please let me know if this is possible in JMeter if Yes how I can run two threads parallel after completion of first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't something which is provided in JMeter out-of-the-box as currently there is no way to jump over the number of threads which are defined on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level so you'll need to do some coding in order to work it around, i.e.:

- Use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (or [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor))
- Develop custom sampler i.e. basing on [ExampleSampler](https://apache.googlesource.com/jmeter/+/trunk/src/examples/org/apache/jmeter/examples/sampler/ExampleSampler.java) which spawns more threads in order to simulate AJAX parallel calls

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article for more details and some reference implementation examples.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I copied the Jar in the JMeter folder and able to see the Example sampler. Now I want to use the JMeter cookies and variable in to request, How i can use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the earlier request I parameterised session id which i am using in my ajax request but the Example Sampler is not sending 
the session id in the post request. Checked in webserver logs.
Post Request: https://some-domain.com/XYZ/MyReqest.php?session=${session_ID}

Comment: Have you seen the following lines: `Disclaimer: the example ajax-sampler source code is provided for your reference only. It’s not a fully functional sampler and doesn’t support components like the HTTP Header Manager, HTTP Authorization Manager, etc.`

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, The code is working fine. Now i need that connection persistent up to test execution time. Any way to create async persistent call.